# Why does a published event on my form not show in the editor

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I have added a published event to my main form, expeecting it would show up in the editor, but it doesn't.
Am I doing something wrong, or is this just not the case?

```
THIFISongEndEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; EstimatedEndTime: TDateTime) of object;

  TMain = class(TForm)
[...]
  published
    property OnSongEnd: THIFISongEndEvent read FOnSongEnd write SetOnSongEnd;
```

EDIT: Added Code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Published properties of `TComponent` descendants are visible in the Object Inspector only when these components are registered in a design-time package. Otherwise, you would not even be able to drop the component onto the Form.

As Forms are usually designed in the Form Designer, they are probably not registered for design-time, and thus their published properties added on top of the base `TForm` properties cannot be known by the Object Inspector.